# Ubuntu -If command seems do not provide else outcome

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I do not understand why my if script is not working. When I have internet connection in Linux it displays the online phrase. When I have no internet connection still displays the online phrase instead the offline.

```
#!/bin/bash
# system_page - A script to monitor various connections and produce
# system information in HTML file

##### Constants
TITLE="Monitor Information for $HOSTNAME"
RIGHT_NOW=$(date +"%x %r %Z")
TIME_STAMP="Updated on $RIGHT_NOW by $USER"
# clear the screen
clear

echo -e "GET http://google.com HTTP/1.0\n\n" | nc google.com 80 >   /dev/null 2>&1



function net_info
{
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
echo "Online"
echo "<h2 style="background-color:#00FF00"><font size="6"> INTERNET IS CONNECTED</h2>"
else
echo "Offline"
echo "<h2 style="background-color:#FF0000"><font size="6"> INTERNET IS NOT CONNECTED</h2>"
fi
}
##### Main
cat <<- _EOF_
<html>
<head>
<title style="background-color:#0000FF">$TITLE</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>$TITLE</h1>
<p>$TIME_STAMP</p>
$(net_info)  
</body>
</html>
_EOF_
```

Comment: It's because nearly everything in bash is a command and after doing your check, you're defining a function--which is successful, so the status code is 0.  You should move the check into the function just before you check the status, or save off the status in a variable and check the variable in the net_info function.

Comment: Thank you so much, It works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jszameister help it works when I moved the line inside the function like that

```
function net_info
{
echo -e "GET http://google.com HTTP/1.0\n\n" | nc google.com 80 > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
echo "Online"
echo "<h2 style="background-color:#00FF00"><font size="6"> INTERNET IS CONNECTED</h2>"
else
echo "Offline"
echo "<h2 style="background-color:#FF0000"><font size="6"> INTERNET IS NOT CONNECTED</h2>"
fi
}
```